# How many quarters between two dates?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

```
NSCalendar *calendar= [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSCalendarUnit unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *dateStart = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:start];
quarterStart = [dateStart quarter];
NSDateComponents *dateEnd = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:end];
quarterEnd = [dateEnd quarter];
```

Having two NSDate start and end and extracting start quarter and end quarter i need to know the differences in quarters between these 2 dates.

I know that i could divide the total days / 90 days but i'm looking at another solution having only these data.

Any hints ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved using that, cause the other suggested answer not works for an Apple's bug on quarter Unit.

```
numberOfQuarters = (4 - startQuarter) + ((endYear -1 - startYear) * 4) + endQuarter;
```

Comment: Can you expand on what bug? Have you filed a report?

Answer (score 2):

You should try:

```
NSDateComponents *result = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSQuarterCalendarUnit fromDate:start toDate:end options:0];
NSInteger numberOfQuaters = [result quarter];
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps :) Do you think other mine solution would be also good (even if not too ... elegant) ?

Comment: See Session 117 from WWDC 2011 at developer.apple.com. It contains a lot of useful information about calendar calculations and why you should never perform it manually.

Comment: the code you've posted should works as 'standalone' ? or i need to first alloc NSCalendar ? I'm trying but i receive always result = 0

Comment: Thanks, the answer is correct but for an Apple's bug about Quarter it not works for now.